# Weird error occured for calculating average datetime

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I used to code below to calculate the average data time for a whole day and its corresponding data
import numpy as np

import numpy as np

```
location2='C:\\Users\\Poon\\Downloads\\20211014_SBS_BEMS\\Test for Workday.csv'
csvfiles2=glob.glob(location2)

df3=pd.DataFrame()

for file_new_2 in csvfiles2: 
    df3=pd.read_csv(file_new_2)
    df4=pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(df3.iloc[:,1], errors = "coerce"),], axis = 1)
    df4=df4.groupby(np.arange(len(df4))//24).mean()
    df5=pd.concat([ df3.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.to_numeric)], axis = 1)
    df5=df5.groupby(np.arange(len(df5))//24).mean()

print(df4)
print(df5)
df6 = pd.merge(df4, df5,left_index=True,right_index=True)
print(df6)
df6.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Poon\\Downloads\\Test\\TestW-2.csv")
```

The original data is shown below

```
1/6/2019 0:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
1/6/2019 1:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
1/6/2019 2:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
1/6/2019 3:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
1/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
1/6/2019 5:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
1/6/2019 6:00   0.45    0.000667    0.001   0.000167    0.000167    0
1/6/2019 7:00   0.55    0.1175  0.18    0.053667    0.116667    0
1/6/2019 8:00   0   0.075833    0.388667    0.0935  0.294333    0
1/6/2019 9:00   0   0.0785  0.5015  0.145333    0.3555  0
1/6/2019 10:00  0   0.141   0.473667    0.125   0.347667    0
1/6/2019 11:00  0   0.145   0.476333    0.135833    0.338833    0
1/6/2019 12:00  0.283333    0.1555  0.4975  0.140333    0.356667    0
1/6/2019 13:00  0.716667    0.175   0.475   0.140167    0.333833    0
1/6/2019 14:00  0   0.181167    0.497   0.140167    0.356   0
1/6/2019 15:00  0   0.185167    0.497333    0.1355  0.360667    0
1/6/2019 16:00  0   0.184833    0.493333    0.126333    0.367333    0
1/6/2019 17:00  0   0.231167    0.4975  0.129   0.365667    0
1/6/2019 18:00  0.283333    0.215167    0.518667    0.145833    0.373   0
1/6/2019 19:00  0.716667    0.191167    0.541667    0.1565  0.383667    0
1/6/2019 20:00  0   0.193167    0.529833    0.143667    0.3855  0
1/6/2019 21:00  0   0.1885  0.465667    0.099   0.365667    0
1/6/2019 22:00  0   0.1355  0.283   0.056667    0.228833    0
1/6/2019 23:00  0   0.005167    0.012333    0.003333    0.01    0
2/6/2019 0:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 1:00   0.25    0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 2:00   0.75    0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 3:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 5:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 6:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 7:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 8:00   0   0.001667    0.000667    0   0.000333    0
2/6/2019 9:00   0.933333    0.1245  0.2135  0.038833    0.170833    0
2/6/2019 10:00  0.066667    0.1965  0.411   0.0795  0.330667    0
2/6/2019 11:00  0   0.184333    0.370667    0.074333    0.295833    0
2/6/2019 12:00  0   0.184833    0.386   0.074667    0.311167    0
2/6/2019 13:00  0   0.185667    0.383833    0.074333    0.3095  0
2/6/2019 14:00  0   0.192   0.405833    0.0805  0.325   0
2/6/2019 15:00  0   0.19    0.424667    0.098   0.325667    0
2/6/2019 16:00  0.816667    0.193333    0.434333    0.100667    0.332667    0
2/6/2019 17:00  0.183333    0.186   0.4165  0.079833    0.3375  0
2/6/2019 18:00  0   0.096   0.232333    0.039333    0.190167    0
2/6/2019 19:00  0   0.005167    0.010667    0   0.010667    0
2/6/2019 20:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 21:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 22:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
2/6/2019 23:00  0.383333    0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 0:00   0.616667    0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 1:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 2:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 3:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 5:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 6:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
3/6/2019 7:00   0.833333    0.040167    0.086167    0.023833    0.062833    0
3/6/2019 8:00   0.166667    0.126833    0.466167    0.133667    0.331667    0
3/6/2019 9:00   0   0.170333    0.5055  0.146667    0.358167    0
3/6/2019 10:00  0   0.133   0.501833    0.142333    0.358333    0
3/6/2019 11:00  0   0.117667    0.4995  0.140167    0.358833    0
3/6/2019 12:00  0   0.127833    0.496167    0.140333    0.3545  0
3/6/2019 13:00  0.183333    0.133833    0.4985  0.140667    0.357167    0
3/6/2019 14:00  0.816667    0.123333    0.501333    0.140667    0.359667    0
3/6/2019 15:00  0   0.123833    0.497333    0.139833    0.356333    0
3/6/2019 16:00  0   0.151333    0.502667    0.141167    0.3605  0
3/6/2019 17:00  0   0.190833    0.507833    0.145   0.362833    0
3/6/2019 18:00  0   0.103667    0.520833    0.148167    0.371   0
3/6/2019 19:00  0   0.150833    0.5225  0.146833    0.375333    0
3/6/2019 20:00  0.733333    0.199667    0.522   0.1435  0.378167    0
3/6/2019 21:00  0.266667    0.186833    0.513   0.139667    0.364167    0.012833
3/6/2019 22:00  0   0.1845  0.463167    0.136167    0.257167    0.067167
3/6/2019 23:00  0   0.156833    0.274167    0.0805  0.033333    0.151333
4/6/2019 0:00   0   0.018667    0.021333    0.000833    0   0.018667
4/6/2019 1:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
4/6/2019 2:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
4/6/2019 3:00   0.133333    0   0   0   0   0
4/6/2019 4:00   0.866667    0   0   0   0   0
4/6/2019 5:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
4/6/2019 6:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
4/6/2019 7:00   0   0.0215  0.06    0.013   0.037333    0.010333
4/6/2019 8:00   0   0.084833    0.448167    0.122   0.306333    0.019667
4/6/2019 9:00   0   0.0605  0.5015  0.142167    0.358333    0
4/6/2019 10:00  0   0.169167    0.5025  0.141667    0.359667    0
4/6/2019 11:00  0.933333    0.1355  0.501667    0.141167    0.359333    0
4/6/2019 12:00  0.066667    0.1225  0.377333    0.111333    0.266   0
4/6/2019 13:00  0   0.117667    0.3765  0.105167    0.269833    0
4/6/2019 14:00  0   0.136   0.5005  0.141167    0.358667    0
4/6/2019 15:00  0   0.193833    0.506333    0.1435  0.3615  0
4/6/2019 16:00  0   0.3365  0.5145  0.149833    0.3635  0
4/6/2019 17:00  0.183333    0.3645  0.526667    0.153   0.373   0
4/6/2019 18:00  0.816667    0.2955  0.5295  0.152167    0.3765  0
4/6/2019 19:00  0   0.197333    0.5215  0.143833    0.375833    0
4/6/2019 20:00  0   0.185167    0.52    0.142333    0.3705  0.007667
4/6/2019 21:00  0   0.185167    0.514   0.130333    0.308167    0.0775
4/6/2019 22:00  0   0.185333    0.464667    0.115833    0.2615  0.0895
4/6/2019 23:00  0   0.185   0.325833    0.112167    0.044   0.161667
5/6/2019 0:00   0.2 0.184333    0.304333    0.109   0   0.185333
5/6/2019 1:00   0.8 0.079667    0.1345  0.050333    0   0.078333
5/6/2019 2:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
5/6/2019 3:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
5/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
5/6/2019 5:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
5/6/2019 6:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
5/6/2019 7:00   0   0.013333    0.067667    0.01    0.038   0.0195
5/6/2019 8:00   0.9 0.0225  0.456667    0.116333    0.310333    0.0305
5/6/2019 9:00   0.1 0.059833    0.505833    0.143167    0.361   0
5/6/2019 10:00  0   0.126   0.498833    0.141333    0.3565  0
5/6/2019 11:00  0   0.129833    0.496167    0.138   0.357333    0
5/6/2019 12:00  0   0.1175  0.345667    0.1005  0.244833    0
5/6/2019 13:00  0   0.118667    0.352333    0.0995  0.252333    0
5/6/2019 14:00  0   0.128833    0.4985  0.14    0.3565  0
5/6/2019 15:00  0.916667    0.128667    0.498   0.1405  0.3565  0
5/6/2019 16:00  0.083333    0.1395  0.499333    0.141   0.357667    0
5/6/2019 17:00  0   0.170333    0.505333    0.146   0.358833    0
5/6/2019 18:00  0   0.128333    0.517333    0.148   0.368   0
5/6/2019 19:00  0   0.168167    0.523   0.1455  0.377333    0
5/6/2019 20:00  0   0.194333    0.526833    0.144   0.359833    0.02
5/6/2019 21:00  0.1 0.138   0.5285  0.138833    0.301   0.087667
5/6/2019 22:00  0.9 0.006167    0.421667    0.133833    0.174833    0.110667
5/6/2019 23:00  0   0   0.331833    0.1235  0.019167    0.179
6/6/2019 0:00   0   0   0.1565  0.06    0   0.092667
6/6/2019 1:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
6/6/2019 2:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
6/6/2019 3:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
6/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
6/6/2019 5:00   0.733333    0   0   0   0   0
6/6/2019 6:00   0.266667    0   0   0   0   0
6/6/2019 7:00   0   0   0.079333    0.020333    0.046167    0.012833
6/6/2019 8:00   0   0   0.452667    0.128   0.3035  0.017167
6/6/2019 9:00   0   0.072667    0.496833    0.141167    0.354667    0
6/6/2019 10:00  0   0.145833    0.495833    0.141333    0.353833    0
6/6/2019 11:00  0   0.124667    0.4925  0.14    0.351667    0
6/6/2019 12:00  0.883333    0.114   0.332667    0.086333    0.245   0
6/6/2019 13:00  0.116667    0.119   0.347333    0.091   0.255667    0
6/6/2019 14:00  0   0.121667    0.502833    0.140667    0.361167    0
6/6/2019 15:00  0   0.127167    0.502167    0.1405  0.361   0
6/6/2019 16:00  0   0.139833    0.502667    0.141167    0.360833    0
6/6/2019 17:00  0   0.171   0.509   0.145833    0.361833    0
6/6/2019 18:00  0   0.1695  0.521   0.147167    0.373667    0
6/6/2019 19:00  0.983333    0.179833    0.5245  0.148667    0.375667    0
6/6/2019 20:00  0.016667    0.184167    0.524   0.148167    0.3535  0.023667
6/6/2019 21:00  0   0.1855  0.513667    0.149333    0.2585  0.1055
6/6/2019 22:00  0   0.185   0.405833    0.147833    0.093833    0.156
6/6/2019 23:00  0   0.185667    0.338833    0.137833    0.010667    0.182333
7/6/2019 0:00   0   0.181167    0.334333    0.129833    0.0185  0.181667
7/6/2019 1:00   0   0.063333    0.104   0.044833    0.000333    0.060833
7/6/2019 2:00   0.533333    0   0   0   0   0
7/6/2019 3:00   0.466667    0   0   0   0   0
7/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
7/6/2019 5:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
7/6/2019 6:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
7/6/2019 7:00   0   0.009833    0.0295  0.009167    0.010333    0.008167
7/6/2019 8:00   0   0.036833    0.41    0.120333    0.265667    0.021833
7/6/2019 9:00   0.233333    0.108667    0.538   0.155   0.382333    0
7/6/2019 10:00  0.766667    0.201333    0.529667    0.150167    0.378   0
7/6/2019 11:00  0   0.180667    0.509667    0.143833    0.364833    0
7/6/2019 12:00  0   0.2525  0.3615  0.106333    0.255   0
7/6/2019 13:00  0   0.196667    0.357167    0.104333    0.250833    0
7/6/2019 14:00  0   0.1915  0.503333    0.142   0.3605  0
7/6/2019 15:00  0   0.265333    0.508333    0.144833    0.362667    0
7/6/2019 16:00  0.233333    0.302333    0.503167    0.144333    0.358833    0
7/6/2019 17:00  0.766667    0.316333    0.492333    0.1445  0.347   0
7/6/2019 18:00  0   0.26    0.521333    0.148   0.372   0
7/6/2019 19:00  0   0.192   0.522333    0.143667    0.366333    0.010667
7/6/2019 20:00  0   0.193   0.546167    0.1385  0.324667    0.081
7/6/2019 21:00  0   0.190167    0.548167    0.144667    0.311833    0.093667
7/6/2019 22:00  0   0.062833    0.4365  0.132833    0.1685  0.131667
7/6/2019 23:00  0   0   0.292667    0.1265  0.000667    0.161
8/6/2019 0:00   0.7 0   0.040167    0.021   0   0.022
8/6/2019 1:00   0.3 0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 2:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 3:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 5:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 6:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 7:00   0.333333    0.005   0.0255  0.0005  0.014167    0.009
8/6/2019 8:00   0.666667    0.025   0.362   0.077167    0.203833    0.073833
8/6/2019 9:00   0   0.0655  0.502   0.114   0.2965  0.093167
8/6/2019 10:00  0   0.117167    0.481167    0.119667    0.267333    0.093333
8/6/2019 11:00  0   0.113333    0.479833    0.122   0.265667    0.093833
8/6/2019 12:00  0   0.132833    0.523833    0.137167    0.295833    0.0935
8/6/2019 13:00  0   0.278667    0.384   0.143833    0.147   0.093
8/6/2019 14:00  0.1 0.299833    0.4315  0.1415  0.196   0.094
8/6/2019 15:00  0.9 0.298333    0.487167    0.132   0.262833    0.0935
8/6/2019 16:00  0   0.287167    0.381667    0.1435  0.1455  0.093333
8/6/2019 17:00  0   0.161   0.382667    0.058667    0.231   0.093667
8/6/2019 18:00  0   0.09    0.403333    0.003333    0.303   0.093167
8/6/2019 19:00  0   0.1485  0.319   0.006667    0.2175  0.092333
8/6/2019 20:00  0   0.067667    0.106333    0   0.073833    0.030333
8/6/2019 21:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 22:00  0.816667    0   0   0   0   0
8/6/2019 23:00  0.183333    0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 0:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 1:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 2:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 3:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 4:00   0   0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 5:00   0.433333    0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 6:00   0.566667    0   0   0   0   0
9/6/2019 7:00   0   0   0.003667    0   0.002667    0.001333
9/6/2019 8:00   0   0   0.227667    0.0425  0.119833    0.061667
9/6/2019 9:00   0   0.005833    0.495167    0.134   0.214833    0.146167
9/6/2019 10:00  0   0.004167    0.507667    0.139167    0.238833    0.132333
9/6/2019 11:00  0   0   0.448333    0.144833    0.153167    0.1485
9/6/2019 12:00  0.116667    0   0.336   0.14    0.000667    0.186333
9/6/2019 13:00  0.883333    0   0.337667    0.140833    0   0.186333
9/6/2019 14:00  0   0   0.336333    0.139667    0   0.185167
9/6/2019 15:00  0   0   0.339333    0.143667    0   0.186
9/6/2019 16:00  0   0   0.344667    0.147833    0   0.186333
9/6/2019 17:00  0   0.088167    0.343167    0.147667    0   0.185333
9/6/2019 18:00  0   0.185167    0.341833    0.146667    0   0.186
9/6/2019 19:00  0   0.185667    0.3385  0.141333    0   0.186333
9/6/2019 20:00  0.733333    0.186   0.331833    0.1355  0   0.186167
9/6/2019 21:00  0.266667    0.184333    0.304833    0.11    0   0.185167
9/6/2019 22:00  0   0.1765  0.289833    0.101667    0   0.176833
9/6/2019 23:00  0   0.044167    0.0735  0.024667    0   0.044
10/6/2019 0:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
10/6/2019 1:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
10/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
10/6/2019 3:00  0.15    0   0   0   0   0
10/6/2019 4:00  0.85    0   0   0   0   0
10/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
10/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
10/6/2019 7:00  0   0.004   0.043667    0.014   0.021   0.009667
10/6/2019 8:00  0   0.015833    0.441667    0.123667    0.3 0.020333
10/6/2019 9:00  0   0.0725  0.539667    0.144   0.395667    0
10/6/2019 10:00 0.133333    0.133833    0.539333    0.1405  0.3975  0
10/6/2019 11:00 0.866667    0.1155  0.539333    0.140167    0.397833    0
10/6/2019 12:00 0   0.116   0.392667    0.109167    0.2835  0
10/6/2019 13:00 0   0.116833    0.388333    0.103   0.284333    0
10/6/2019 14:00 0   0.130167    0.5365  0.140667    0.394833    0
10/6/2019 15:00 0   0.124833    0.5295  0.139667    0.389   0
10/6/2019 16:00 0   0.1665  0.540833    0.143667    0.395667    0
10/6/2019 17:00 0.566667    0.269667    0.552167    0.153833    0.397667    0
10/6/2019 18:00 0.433333    0.2465  0.536833    0.151333    0.386167    0
10/6/2019 19:00 0   0.191833    0.525167    0.147333    0.369167    0.004833
10/6/2019 20:00 0   0.19    0.548833    0.148667    0.3255  0.0725
10/6/2019 21:00 0   0.187833    0.446   0.147333    0.203333    0.096833
10/6/2019 22:00 0   0.188167    0.3685  0.147   0.058833    0.159
10/6/2019 23:00 0   0.1815  0.324667    0.132833    0   0.181167
11/6/2019 0:00  0.216667    0.0585  0.096333    0.033167    0   0.055667
11/6/2019 1:00  0.783333    0   0   0   0   0
11/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
11/6/2019 3:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
11/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
11/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
11/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
11/6/2019 7:00  0   0.025167    0.066833    0.0075  0.044333    0.015333
11/6/2019 8:00  0.866667    0.044833    0.459833    0.1125  0.322   0.024667
11/6/2019 9:00  0.133333    0.0525  0.536667    0.144   0.392333    0
11/6/2019 10:00 0   0.1615  0.5365  0.142333    0.393333    0
11/6/2019 11:00 0   0.152167    0.5345  0.140333    0.392833    0
11/6/2019 12:00 0   0.115667    0.387   0.106333    0.2805  0
11/6/2019 13:00 0   0.1285  0.385167    0.108833    0.275167    0
11/6/2019 14:00 0.083333    0.123833    0.536833    0.140833    0.395833    0
11/6/2019 15:00 0.916667    0.160833    0.5365  0.141333    0.392833    0
11/6/2019 16:00 0   0.147   0.538667    0.144667    0.393   0
11/6/2019 17:00 0   0.150333    0.5435  0.149667    0.393333    0
11/6/2019 18:00 0   0.1105  0.537333    0.151167    0.386   0
11/6/2019 19:00 0   0.161833    0.525833    0.146167    0.357667    0.019833
11/6/2019 20:00 0   0.185   0.537167    0.137833    0.311   0.088
11/6/2019 21:00 0   0.1855  0.487   0.117167    0.277833    0.093833
11/6/2019 22:00 0.533333    0.185667    0.438833    0.136   0.2105  0.093667
11/6/2019 23:00 0.466667    0.125333    0.261   0.100167    0.0965  0.062833
12/6/2019 0:00  0   0.003833    0.010833    0.003167    0.005   0.001833
12/6/2019 1:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
12/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
12/6/2019 3:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
12/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
12/6/2019 5:00  0.166667    0   0   0   0   0
12/6/2019 6:00  0.833333    0.007333    0.016   0.002   0.011333    0.0035
12/6/2019 7:00  0   0.106167    0.307667    0.036667    0.201   0.0675
12/6/2019 8:00  0   0.0165  0.501167    0.114333    0.358833    0.029
12/6/2019 9:00  0   0.074167    0.537167    0.143167    0.393667    0
12/6/2019 10:00 0   0.1505  0.535   0.142333    0.392167    0
12/6/2019 11:00 0   0.156333    0.537333    0.140833    0.396   0
12/6/2019 12:00 0.216667    0.113167    0.377667    0.109   0.267167    0
12/6/2019 13:00 0.783333    0.130667    0.365167    0.102833    0.261667    0
12/6/2019 14:00 0   0.1215  0.541833    0.14    0.401   0
12/6/2019 15:00 0   0.127333    0.5355  0.140833    0.394333    0
12/6/2019 16:00 0   0.1305  0.532333    0.141   0.391167    0
12/6/2019 17:00 0   0.158167    0.540333    0.145667    0.392   0
12/6/2019 18:00 0   0.149167    0.5365  0.150833    0.383667    0.001
12/6/2019 19:00 0.15    0.184167    0.552667    0.148   0.3105  0.094333
12/6/2019 20:00 0.85    0.185   0.550333    0.148667    0.2325  0.168833
12/6/2019 21:00 0   0.172333    0.400667    0.143   0.071833    0.179333
12/6/2019 22:00 0   0.037   0.353833    0.122   0.118833    0.111667
12/6/2019 23:00 0   0   0.216333    0.068167    0.091333    0.0545
13/6/2019 0:00  0   0   0.0025  0.000667    0.001   0.000333
13/6/2019 1:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
13/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
13/6/2019 3:00  0.783333    0   0   0   0   0
13/6/2019 4:00  0.216667    0   0   0   0   0
13/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
13/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
13/6/2019 7:00  0   0   0.097   0.0265  0.053167    0.019667
13/6/2019 8:00  0   0   0.484333    0.133   0.324667    0.030333
13/6/2019 9:00  0   0.065667    0.536333    0.143167    0.392167    0
13/6/2019 10:00 0.483333    0.145167    0.529333    0.141833    0.386833    0
13/6/2019 11:00 0.516667    0.127667    0.5245  0.1385  0.3845  0
13/6/2019 12:00 0   0.113333    0.369833    0.097167    0.271667    0
13/6/2019 13:00 0   0.149   0.370333    0.101833    0.267167    0
13/6/2019 14:00 0   0.149167    0.530167    0.140167    0.389167    0
13/6/2019 15:00 0   0.12    0.528833    0.14    0.387833    0
13/6/2019 16:00 0   0.136333    0.53    0.140667    0.388833    0
13/6/2019 17:00 0.4 0.1455  0.531833    0.140833    0.390667    0
13/6/2019 18:00 0.6 0.1295  0.5265  0.1445  0.381   0
13/6/2019 19:00 0   0.182667    0.513833    0.1385  0.375167    0
13/6/2019 20:00 0   0.190667    0.439833    0.061333    0.373333    0
13/6/2019 21:00 0   0.184667    0.496333    0.134833    0.351833    0.003333
13/6/2019 22:00 0   0.178333    0.448667    0.141667    0.239833    0.069167
13/6/2019 23:00 0   0.052333    0.345667    0.112   0.112167    0.115167
14/6/2019 0:00  0.083333    0   0.036667    0.0135  0   0.022333
14/6/2019 1:00  0.916667    0   0   0   0   0
14/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
14/6/2019 3:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
14/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
14/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
14/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
14/6/2019 7:00  0   0   0.041167    0.014   0.015333    0.0105
14/6/2019 8:00  0.716667    0.007   0.43    0.123333    0.2855  0.0195
14/6/2019 9:00  0.283333    0.054   0.534167    0.141667    0.391833    0
14/6/2019 10:00 0   0.113333    0.537   0.140333    0.397   0
14/6/2019 11:00 0   0.146667    0.538333    0.140667    0.395667    0
14/6/2019 12:00 0   0.120833    0.378167    0.105167    0.2725  0
14/6/2019 13:00 0   0.211833    0.382667    0.106   0.275833    0
14/6/2019 14:00 0   0.309333    0.539667    0.147833    0.390667    0
14/6/2019 15:00 1   0.305833    0.544   0.15    0.392833    0
14/6/2019 16:00 0   0.315   0.548667    0.154   0.3945  0
14/6/2019 17:00 0   0.331   0.547667    0.1545  0.392667    0
14/6/2019 18:00 0   0.265833    0.5355  0.151333    0.383   0
14/6/2019 19:00 0   0.188667    0.524167    0.147167    0.367   0.010167
14/6/2019 20:00 0   0.1855  0.529833    0.146667    0.306333    0.080667
14/6/2019 21:00 0   0.185167    0.452333    0.126   0.2335  0.093333
14/6/2019 22:00 0.783333    0.191667    0.500667    0.119167    0.288333    0.0935
14/6/2019 23:00 0.216667    0.188   0.414333    0.110667    0.166667    0.1305
15/6/2019 0:00  0   0.164833    0.298833    0.120167    0.000833    0.165167
15/6/2019 1:00  0   0.0255  0.052833    0.021333    0   0.026667
15/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
15/6/2019 3:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
15/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
15/6/2019 5:00  0.433333    0   0   0   0   0
15/6/2019 6:00  0.566667    0   0   0   0   0
15/6/2019 7:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
15/6/2019 8:00  0   0.091833    0.144833    0   0.104167    0.047167
15/6/2019 9:00  0   0.276667    0.385667    0.016   0.279   0.0895
15/6/2019 10:00 0   0.2495  0.411833    0.037667    0.318667    0.053667
15/6/2019 11:00 0   0.151   0.3745  0.006333    0.279667    0.085667
15/6/2019 12:00 0.133333    0.173167    0.339667    0   0.2275  0.108167
15/6/2019 13:00 0.866667    0.188667    0.401833    0.0015  0.294167    0.101
15/6/2019 14:00 0   0.194   0.433333    0.022833    0.311333    0.093833
15/6/2019 15:00 0   0.189333    0.387333    0.005667    0.2805  0.093833
15/6/2019 16:00 0   0.173167    0.410667    0   0.3135  0.093
15/6/2019 17:00 0   0.179   0.407833    0   0.311333    0.0935
15/6/2019 18:00 0   0.093667    0.343167    0.000333    0.245833    0.093667
15/6/2019 19:00 0   0   0.371833    0.009667    0.2665  0.0935
15/6/2019 20:00 0.566667    0   0.152333    0   0.084833    0.062167
15/6/2019 21:00 0.433333    0   0.005167    0   0.003   0.001333
15/6/2019 22:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
15/6/2019 23:00 0   0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 0:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 1:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 3:00  0.216667    0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 4:00  0.783333    0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
16/6/2019 7:00  0   0   0.011833    0.006   0   0.011833
16/6/2019 8:00  0   0.000333    0.0085  0.004   0   0.008167
16/6/2019 9:00  0   0.053667    0.185333    0.075167    0.0015  0.097333
16/6/2019 10:00 0   0.026   0.425667    0.122833    0.115167    0.185
16/6/2019 11:00 0.85    0   0.437833    0.125667    0.126833    0.186
16/6/2019 12:00 0.15    0   0.417833    0.130333    0.101667    0.1865
16/6/2019 13:00 0   0   0.426667    0.136667    0.105   0.185833
16/6/2019 14:00 0   0   0.417167    0.137   0.108833    0.166667
16/6/2019 15:00 0   0   0.470667    0.139333    0.232667    0.099833
16/6/2019 16:00 0   0   0.435833    0.139833    0.203333    0.093833
16/6/2019 17:00 0   0.011833    0.482833    0.142167    0.262333    0.078333
16/6/2019 18:00 0.583333    0.147333    0.445833    0.140833    0.158833    0.145667
16/6/2019 19:00 0.416667    0.1855  0.355667    0.135333    0.023833    0.186
16/6/2019 20:00 0   0.185333    0.306833    0.111   0   0.185167
16/6/2019 21:00 0   0.184667    0.304333    0.108833    0   0.185167
16/6/2019 22:00 0   0.185833    0.317833    0.121667    0   0.185833
16/6/2019 23:00 0   0.153833    0.270833    0.110333    0   0.1555
17/6/2019 0:00  0   0.015667    0.0285  0.013   0   0.017333
17/6/2019 1:00  0.216667    0   0   0   0   0
17/6/2019 2:00  0.783333    0   0   0   0   0
17/6/2019 3:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
17/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
17/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
17/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
17/6/2019 7:00  0   0.044333    0.110167    0.017   0.079167    0.010833
17/6/2019 8:00  0.216667    0.081   0.493667    0.124667    0.3565  0.009167
17/6/2019 9:00  0.783333    0.066833    0.537   0.143667    0.392667    0
17/6/2019 10:00 0   0.131   0.5375  0.1425  0.3945  0
17/6/2019 11:00 0   0.122667    0.535   0.139833    0.395333    0
17/6/2019 12:00 0   0.1125  0.394667    0.101667    0.291167    0
17/6/2019 13:00 0   0.121833    0.3835  0.1025  0.28    0
17/6/2019 14:00 0   0.147333    0.5345  0.1405  0.3925  0
17/6/2019 15:00 0.4 0.144667    0.532333    0.139833    0.391833    0
17/6/2019 16:00 0.6 0.148167    0.5325  0.140833    0.390667    0
17/6/2019 17:00 0   0.146167    0.537833    0.1425  0.395   0
17/6/2019 18:00 0   0.093   0.529833    0.143667    0.385167    0
17/6/2019 19:00 0   0.185833    0.524333    0.146667    0.376333    0
17/6/2019 20:00 0   0.2005  0.533167    0.149   0.362333    0.021167
17/6/2019 21:00 0   0.185167    0.528667    0.147167    0.294   0.088833
17/6/2019 22:00 0.166667    0.1255  0.401167    0.1385  0.1575  0.104
17/6/2019 23:00 0.833333    0.0035  0.148667    0.0495  0.035833    0.06
18/6/2019 0:00  0   0   0.183   0   0.093333    0.085667
18/6/2019 1:00  0   0   0.180167    0   0.03    0.138167
18/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0.219333    0   0.103333    0.1105
18/6/2019 3:00  0   0   0.205833    0   0.0385  0.155833
18/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0.172667    0   0.038833    0.125
18/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0.177833    0   0.058667    0.114167
18/6/2019 6:00  0.85    0   0.286667    0   0.189833    0.092833
18/6/2019 7:00  0.15    0   0.296   0.068833    0.1355  0.0925
18/6/2019 8:00  0   0   0.4965  0.140667    0.321333    0.031333
18/6/2019 9:00  0   0.055667    0.536333    0.141333    0.393667    0
18/6/2019 10:00 0   0.151167    0.538   0.140833    0.397167    0
18/6/2019 11:00 0   0.143   0.535167    0.140667    0.393667    0
18/6/2019 12:00 0   0.118167    0.389   0.107833    0.2805  0
18/6/2019 13:00 0.883333    0.193167    0.373333    0.100167    0.273   0
18/6/2019 14:00 0.116667    0.174667    0.537167    0.1415  0.3935  0
18/6/2019 15:00 0   0.155167    0.535   0.141333    0.391833    0
18/6/2019 16:00 0   0.163   0.534833    0.1405  0.395   0
18/6/2019 17:00 0   0.152833    0.541   0.144   0.3955  0
18/6/2019 18:00 0   0.0995  0.532   0.144333    0.384667    0.003
18/6/2019 19:00 0.083333    0.153167    0.525333    0.139167    0.354167    0.035667
18/6/2019 20:00 0.916667    0.190167    0.546167    0.146   0.326833    0.072667
18/6/2019 21:00 0   0.193667    0.546333    0.147667    0.317667    0.081167
18/6/2019 22:00 0   0.185667    0.520167    0.140333    0.305667    0.076667
18/6/2019 23:00 0   0.061   0.463333    0.130833    0.247167    0.085
19/6/2019 0:00  0   0   0.219667    0.064   0.080167    0.0715
19/6/2019 1:00  0   0   0.004667    0   0   0.004333
19/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
19/6/2019 3:00  0.883333    0   0   0   0   0
19/6/2019 4:00  0.116667    0   0   0   0   0
19/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
19/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
19/6/2019 7:00  0   0   0.149667    0.006833    0.074333    0.0675
19/6/2019 8:00  0   0   0.492833    0.112333    0.330833    0.0525
19/6/2019 9:00  0.083333    0.064   0.534833    0.142167    0.391167    0
19/6/2019 10:00 0.916667    0.113167    0.530167    0.1405  0.389333    0
19/6/2019 11:00 0   0.119667    0.534   0.1405  0.393167    0
19/6/2019 12:00 0   0.119167    0.3875  0.107   0.2795  0
19/6/2019 13:00 0   0.117667    0.38    0.102667    0.275333    0
19/6/2019 14:00 0   0.1245  0.529   0.135667    0.393333    0
19/6/2019 15:00 0.033333    0.182667    0.536333    0.1405  0.395   0
19/6/2019 16:00 0.966667    0.204667    0.534833    0.140833    0.393   0
19/6/2019 17:00 0   0.211833    0.504167    0.140167    0.363667    0
19/6/2019 18:00 0   0.155833    0.497333    0.140833    0.355833    0
19/6/2019 19:00 0   0.179667    0.497667    0.141   0.356   0
19/6/2019 20:00 0   0.191333    0.495667    0.139833    0.354   0
19/6/2019 21:00 0   0.1865  0.494167    0.140167    0.3545  0
19/6/2019 22:00 0.2 0.190333    0.497167    0.1405  0.356   0
19/6/2019 23:00 0.8 0.185   0.496167    0.140333    0.355167    0
20/6/2019 0:00  0   0.15    0.4015  0.116333    0.2845  0
20/6/2019 1:00  0   0.014   0.037   0.011833    0.025333    0
20/6/2019 2:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
20/6/2019 3:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
20/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
20/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
20/6/2019 6:00  0.833333    0   0   0   0   0
20/6/2019 7:00  0.166667    0.027667    0.070833    0.017167    0.052833    0
20/6/2019 8:00  0   0.115833    0.441167    0.121833    0.318833    0
20/6/2019 9:00  0   0.074333    0.4975  0.1405  0.355667    0
20/6/2019 10:00 0   0.127333    0.4975  0.140833    0.356   0
20/6/2019 11:00 0   0.121   0.4965  0.140833    0.355   0
20/6/2019 12:00 0.733333    0.1125  0.495   0.140167    0.354167    0
20/6/2019 13:00 0.266667    0.123667    0.497833    0.140833    0.3555  0
20/6/2019 14:00 0   0.145833    0.4975  0.141   0.356   0
20/6/2019 15:00 0   0.126167    0.496667    0.140333    0.355   0
20/6/2019 16:00 0   0.121833    0.495333    0.1405  0.3545  0
20/6/2019 17:00 0   0.141167    0.497667    0.1405  0.355833    0
20/6/2019 18:00 0.283333    0.092833    0.4975  0.141   0.356333    0
20/6/2019 19:00 0.716667    0.1635  0.512667    0.1425  0.367667    0
20/6/2019 20:00 0   0.198667    0.52    0.145167    0.374667    0
20/6/2019 21:00 0   0.187667    0.520833    0.1425  0.360167    0.0165
20/6/2019 22:00 0   0.184833    0.421   0.083833    0.252   0.086333
20/6/2019 23:00 0   0.095167    0.369333    0.081333    0.170667    0.107333
21/6/2019 0:00  0   0   0.085167    0.029167    0.009167    0.039833
21/6/2019 1:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
21/6/2019 2:00  0.95    0   0   0   0   0
21/6/2019 3:00  0.05    0   0   0   0   0
21/6/2019 4:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
21/6/2019 5:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
21/6/2019 6:00  0   0   0   0   0   0
21/6/2019 7:00  0   0   0.061833    0.005333    0.0385  0.021833
21/6/2019 8:00  0   0   0.461167    0.105333    0.318167    0.038167
21/6/2019 9:00  0.916667    0.058333    0.532833    0.141   0.3915  0
21/6/2019 10:00 0.083333    0.113167    0.529667    0.140333    0.388833    0
21/6/2019 11:00 0   0.1125  0.537333    0.140667    0.395833    0
21/6/2019 12:00 0   0.113   0.369167    0.098   0.269833    0
21/6/2019 13:00 0   0.112833    0.375833    0.100833    0.274167    0
21/6/2019 14:00 0   0.115833    0.537333    0.140833    0.391833    0.003833
21/6/2019 15:00 0.4 0.2415  0.549667    0.149167    0.3945  0.006167
21/6/2019 16:00 0.6 0.293333    0.5435  0.154   0.387   0
21/6/2019 17:00 0   0.197833    0.544   0.1545  0.3885  0
21/6/2019 18:00 0   0.1115  0.537667    0.1485  0.349   0.043167
21/6/2019 19:00 0   0.000167    0.4875  0.139   0.281667    0.066667
21/6/2019 20:00 0   0   0.4845  0.1355  0.256333    0.092
21/6/2019 21:00 0   0   0.502333    0.121333    0.288667    0.093667
21/6/2019 22:00 0.45    0   0.287833    0.015667    0.177167    0.09
21/6/2019 23:00 0.55    0   0.067833    0   0.0385  0.0245
```

However, the data from 1st to 12th is day and month reversed, but the remaining date is normal. Just like that.

```
6/1/2019    0.125   0.108333    0.305417    0.082083    0.2225
6/2/2019    0.140972    0.0725  0.15375 0.030833    0.1225
6/3/2019    0.150694    0.100889    0.328278    0.092882    0.225
6/4/2019    0.125   0.124778    0.321354    0.090063    0.214583
6/5/2019    0.166667    0.085583    0.333847    0.096222    0.20625
6/6/2019    0.125   0.092729    0.320757    0.093972    0.200882
6/7/2019    0.125   0.133521    0.33534 0.098903    0.204118
6/8/2019    0.166667    0.087083    0.221257    0.050875    0.121667
6/9/2019    0.125   0.044167    0.225   0.0825  0.030417
6/10/2019   0.125   0.102146    0.324736    0.092785    0.208333
6/11/2019   0.166667    0.094778    0.331063    0.09    0.221458
6/12/2019   0.125   0.084326    0.331181    0.089271    0.211417
13/6/2019   0.125   0.08625 0.325243    0.086549    0.227958
14/6/2019   0.166667    0.129986    0.333958    0.091333    0.222882
15/6/2019   0.125   0.089597    0.205069    0.010063    0.138368
16/6/2019   0.125   0.047264    0.238396    0.078625    0.06
17/6/2019   0.166667    0.086486    0.325958    0.088458    0.223771
18/6/2019   0.125   0.09125 0.411299    0.094   0.260806
19/6/2019   0.166667    0.09775 0.346493    0.092326    0.245431
20/6/2019   0.125   0.096833    0.344306    0.094542    0.240028
21/6/2019   0.166667    0.06125 0.312299    0.079965    0.209965
22/6/2019   0.125   0.076667    0.304125    0.076542    0.156271
23/6/2019   0.125   0.007083    0.187125    0.008875    0.114563
24/6/2019   0.159722    0.090674    0.337708    0.094097    0.232764
25/6/2019   0.131944    0.07391 0.338118    0.094993    0.222653
26/6/2019   0.125   0.12    0.307924    0.079243    0.211667
27/6/2019   0.166667    0.120417    0.31625 0.0875  0.2225
28/6/2019   0.125   0.07875 0.300833    0.0775  0.217917
29/6/2019   0.125   0.083333    0.244583    0.0425  0.15625
30/6/2019   0.166667    0.11125 0.21125 0.066667    0.08875
7/1/2019    0.125   0.137556    0.328424    0.091389    0.22934
7/2/2019    0.130556    0.1305  0.327535    0.097451    0.207326
7/3/2019    0.161111    0.096111    0.337278    0.095521    0.229972
7/4/2019    0.125   0.081458    0.340417    0.094653    0.224278
7/5/2019    0.166667    0.114431    0.325361    0.095674    0.207167
7/6/2019    0.125   0.057861    0.320986    0.085313    0.163583
```

How to fix this weird error?

Comment: Can you show the original data from 6/1/2019 to 6/30/2019?

Comment: Updated, please have a look. Originally they are 1/6/2019 to 30/6/2019. But I cannot show more data since it exceeds word limitation.

Comment: No one know? sad